# Diferencia entre row y column en php

Tags: php

Hola muchas veces me confundo porque creo una tabla en `phpMyAdmin` y cuando creo un tabla me esta creando columnas. Pero sin embargo, otras personas crean `rows` un ejemplo:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Machine: localhost
-- Genereertijd: 04 mrt 2013 om 19:05
-- Serverversie: 5.5.24-log
-- PHP-versie: 5.3.13

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Databank: `coffeedb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `coffee`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coffee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `roast` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `review` text,
  `ide` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `coffee`
--

INSERT INTO `coffee` (`id`, `name`, `type`, `price`, `roast`, `country`, `image`, `review`) VALUES
(1, 'Cafe au Lait', 'Classic', 2.25, 'Medium', 'France', 'Images/Coffee/Cafe-Au-Lait.jpg', 'A coffee beverage consisting strong or bold coffee (sometimes espresso) mixed with scalded milk in approximately a 1:1 ratio.'')'),
(2, 'Caffe Americano', 'Espresso', 3.25, 'Medium', 'Italy', 'Images/coffee/caffe_americano.jpg', 'Similar in strength and taste to American-style brewed coffee, there are subtle differences achieved by pulling a fresh shot of espresso for the beverage base.'),
(3, 'Peppermint White Chocolate Mocha', 'Espresso', 3.25, 'Medium', 'Italy', 'Images/coffee/white-chocolate-peppermint-mocha.jpg', 'Espresso with white chocolate and peppermint flavored syrups and steamed milk. Topped with sweetened whipped cream and dark chocolate curls.'),
(4, 'Galao', 'Latte', 4.2, 'Light', 'Portugal', 'Images/Coffee/galao_kaffee_portugal.jpg', 'Galao is a hot drink from Portugal made of espresso and foamed milk');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo desde `phpMyAdmin` crear filas en vez de que columnas. Las columnas se crean por medio del INSERT INTO. Como podría indicar en este código que me crease columnas en vez de que filas.

Answer (score 1):

Primero una explicación rápida de lo más relevante del código expuesto.

Esta parte CREA **una tabla Y sus columnas**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coffee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `roast` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `review` text,
  `ide` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Esta otra **INSERTA registros en una tabla, o crea fila**s, por así llamarlo:

```
INSERT INTO `coffee` (`id`, `name`, `type`, `price`, `roast`, `country`, `image`, `review`) VALUES
(1, 'Cafe au Lait', 'Classic', 2.25, 'Medium', 'France', 'Images/Coffee/Cafe-Au-Lait.jpg', 'A coffee beverage consisting strong or bold coffee (sometimes espresso) mixed with scalded milk in approximately a 1:1 ratio.'')'),
(2, 'Caffe Americano', 'Espresso', 3.25, 'Medium', 'Italy', 'Images/coffee/caffe_americano.jpg', 'Similar in strength and taste to American-style brewed coffee, there are subtle differences achieved by pulling a fresh shot of espresso for the beverage base.'),
(3, 'Peppermint White Chocolate Mocha', 'Espresso', 3.25, 'Medium', 'Italy', 'Images/coffee/white-chocolate-peppermint-mocha.jpg', 'Espresso with white chocolate and peppermint flavored syrups and steamed milk. Topped with sweetened whipped cream and dark chocolate curls.'),
(4, 'Galao', 'Latte', 4.2, 'Light', 'Portugal', 'Images/Coffee/galao_kaffee_portugal.jpg', 'Galao is a hot drink from Portugal made of espresso and foamed milk');
```

---

Ahora, respondiendo a la pregunta, **NO** se pueden crear columnas con INSERT INTO, solo se pueden crear (insertar) filas.

---

Para crear columnas hay dos formas, cuando se crea la tabla (ver código de arriba) y cuando la tabla fue creada anteriormente, lo cual muestro a continuación, utilizando ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE coffee ADD COLUMN cups INT NOT NULL;
```

---

Teniendo en cuenta que la pregunta también habla de phpmyadmin, también es posible agregar filas y columnas a través de su interfaz gráfica, en este video se puede ver como agrgar columnas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ72GCGWPQg

Comment: se me olvido eso de los registros lo estudie pero hace tanto tiempo que no tocaba mysql y php se me ha ido olvidando